# How to convert columns into Numerical data?

Tags: python, pandas, data-conversion

All,

Currently my pandas dataset looks like following, and I would like to convert my dataframe such that it look like following. My requirements are below

**Current Dataframe:**

```
 df.tail()
    age   country   females  males  total year
    96   United States 72700  22700  95400  2010
    97    United States 50300  14500  64800  2010
    98    United States 35000   8730   43700 2010
    99    United States 25200   4920   30100 2010
    100    United State 51200    9570   60800  2010
```

**After Conversion:** [image]

**Note:** *I do recognize that my required conversion is in JSON format, but basically I would like to convert my females and males columns such that I can create Gender column in my dataset and assign values 1 and 2 and also keeping males and females number in dataset*. I am newbie to Python if you could provide explanation with code that will be great!

Comment: Can you show us the data by using df.head() rather than picture

Comment: @W-B.. please see updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a little reshaping `melt`, `map` for the genders, and to_dict to get a list of dictionaries.

```
v = (df.melt(['age', 'country', 'total', 'year'])
       .rename({'variable': 'sex', 'total': 'people'}, axis=1))
v['sex'] = v['sex'].map({'males':1, 'females':2})

data = v.drop('value',1).to_dict('r')
```

```
print(data)
[{'age': 96,
  'country': 'United States',
  'people': 95400,
  'sex': 2,
  'year': 2010},
 {'age': 97,
  'country': 'United States',
  'people': 64800,
  'sex': 2,
  'year': 2010},
  ...
]
```

---

You may instead want JSON, so use

```
json_data = v.drop('value',1).to_json(orient='records')
```

Comment: Thanks! but I would like to keep my data in pandas dataframe

Comment: @biggboss2019 Take a minute, please read the code, understand what it does, and then remove the `.to_dict('r')` part at the end.

Comment: Sorry! I was in rush. But I did realize that  v is in Pandas dataframe